# Calling a locally declared function in Angular's ngOnChanges

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know it's a rather basic question but i just can't seem to find a solution to this. Here it is:

I have an Angular Component, and in that component i have a function.

```
export class RolesListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @ViewChild(DxDataGridComponent) dataGrid: DxDataGridComponent;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.refresh();
    }

    refresh(){
        this.dataGrid.instance.refresh();
    }

}
```

Calling the this.refresh() inside the onchanges doesn't work and gives an error that refresh is undefined.

What can i do to execute either the code inside the function directly in the onchanges, or the function itself.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? Don't you think it's more about your `datagrid.instance.refresh` not being defined ? As you might know (or not), `onChanges` hook gets triggered before `afterViewInit`, which is the one that binds viewchildren to your component.

Comment: Did your component contains the constructor and the `ngOnInit()` method? Can you edit your question adding the error message?

Comment: This should work fine. There is no reason why this.refresh() is not in scope inside class where ngOnChanges is used.

Comment: @trichetriche that might be an issue. Do you have any idea how i can fix the fact that my datagrid object is not defined?

Comment: @Vlad replace `this.dataGrid.instance.refresh()` with `this.dataGrid && this.dataGrid.instance.refresh()` (which is an `if` statement in one line)

Comment: You can also use the parameter of `ngOnChanges`, which is a [`SimpleChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) object, meaning you can use it like `ngOnChangeParam.dataGrid.currentValue` to get the current value of your dataGrid

Comment: @trichetriche I have used the first solution and i'm still getting "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined" as for the second solution, dataGrid is not an input, it's a component i am using that is part of an external library so i cannot call it using the SimpleChanges param.

Comment: @Vlad the error should tell you the line where it bugged : could you check which line it is, and tell us what it is ?

Comment: And f*** me, I meant `this.dataGrid && this.dataGrid.instance && this.dataGrid.instance.refresh()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc

> ngOnChanges Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties

Simply put, if you have any `@input` properties and if u want to detect any changes to those properties, you can use `ngOnChanges`. Since i don't see any input properties in you component that may be why, ngOnchanges doesn't get execute

Comment: I do have an @Input() i just didn't put it in the code snippet.

Comment: then once the input value get changes, angular will fire the onchage method

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue. The issue is I get an error saying refresh() is undefined

Comment: is it  `this.dataGrid.instance.refresh();` this refresh

Comment: Yes. As @trichetriche mentioned in a comment, the issue is that when the onChanges gets triggered the ViewChild hasn't been defined because afterViewInit is triggered after onChanges. But that still leaves me with the problem. How do i use a function from ViewChild variable inside the onChanges handler

Comment: u can simply use an if condition to check whether the datagrid is initiated. `if(this.dataGrid && this.dataGrid.instance ){ this.dataGrid.instance.refresh(); }`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Checking if the datagrid is initiated with an if statement works perfectly!